# hash with array rails not chain value but delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I've tried to insert some Values into this hash were every key is an array but when I print all result just the last value

```
def self.hash_builder(query)

       statistic = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }    

          if !query.empty?

            query.each do |q|

              statistic[:sell].push(q.total_sell.to_i)
              statistic[:price].push(q.total_price.to_f)

            end
          else
            statistic[:sell].push(0)
            statistic[:price].push(0.0)

          end

        return statistic
end
```

I call this method after make a query, and I send to this the query with the new params, but every time i see inside this hash just the last query value

**THIS IS THE RESULT**

[image: right output]

Comment: Works for me. Can you show the value of `query` at the top of the method?

Comment: Try `statistic[:sell] << q.total_sell.to_i`.

Comment: already try this but overwrites the values every time

Comment: Please show the output of `puts query.inspect` or similar (in text); not a screenshot of your app, as we don't know what you did to produce the screenshot.

Comment: @Gene: `Array#push` and `Array#<<` are almost identical, where one works the other should too (except for the valence of `push`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer here because the comment section doesn't allow enough room. You're wrong about `<<`.  It ought to work fine.

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> s = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = [] }
=> {}
irb(main):002:0> s[:sell] << 1
=> [1]
irb(main):003:0> s[:sell] << 2
=> [1, 2]
irb(main):004:0> s[:sell]
=> [1, 2]
irb(main):005:0> s[:price]
=> []
```

But `push` should work, too.

```
irb(main):006:0> s[:sell].push(3)
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I see the problem, every times when i call the model I re-initialize the Hash for that i delete every times the old values.  Thanks !!! A lot !!! with your terminal screen I see my error !!!